# How i can to make a live client chat application for my website's user like Y! Messenger?

Tags: delphi, chat, irc, delphi-xe

How i can to make a live client chat application for my website similar Yahoo! messenger but only on TEXT Based or i want to make a simple program for send and receive text message only (not need live voice transferring , ... )?

I have a website with sql server database (ASP.NET site), in my website user's can sign-up(register) it.
I want to make a client chat program(like Yahoo messenger) for all my website's user, and they use it for live chat.
This means i have a server and a SQL Server DB, all user's resisted in this database. i want to make a application to be able get a username and password and login to chatroom,...

How i can to make a application with this  features? i can use IRC?
There are a open-source software for use it?

I programming with Delphi XE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to roll your own with Indy components that come with Delphi.  There's actually an Indy chat demo available. (grab from their SVN demo repo: https://svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10Demos)

Instructions how to access their SVN repositories: http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/svn.EN.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are a few component libraries that you can buy to help with this project.  One of them is from AidAim software:

http://www.aidaim.com/delphi_messenger_sdk_instant_messaging_sdk_im_sdk.htm

Another option to look at is from Eldos:
http://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/